# Configuring Sphinx for json search

Tags: json, search, sphinx

I am wondering about sphinx real time indexes and it's configuration. I have a mysql table with this columns:

```
filter_id       int(11) AI PK
filter_user_id  int(11)
filter_name     varchar(64)
filter_state    text
```

And I'm storing json in `filter_state`. Now, I want to search through json fields, and configurating Sphinx realtime index.

My config file looks like this:

```
index rt_filters
{
    type = rt
    path = /var/sphinx/data/rt_filters

    rt_field = state 
    rt_attr_uint = filter_user_id
    rt_attr_json = filter_state

    rt_mem_limit = 256M
}

searchd
{
    listen          = 9312
    listen          = 9306:mysql41
    log             = /var/log/sphinx/searchd.log
    query_log       = /var/log/sphinx/query.log
    read_timeout    = 5
    max_children    = 30
    pid_file        = /var/run/searchd.pid
    seamless_rotate = 1
    preopen_indexes = 1
    unlink_old      = 1
    workers         = threads # for RT to work
    binlog_path     = /var/sphinx/data
}
```

But I'm a little confused about duplicating `state` as `rt_field` and `rt_attr_json`. As I understood, Sphinx can search through json when it has `rt_attr_json`. So, why I need to duplicate it as `rt_field`? Or should I query `rt_field` instead of attribute?

Answer (score 0):

Well rt_attr_json is indexed, and the data made available as **attributes**. So you can sort, order, group, and filter by them.

But you need need to duplicate any values you want to 'full-text' search into **fields**. Only fields are full-text indexed. (ie use in the text 'query'/ MATCH())

Comment: unfortunately there is no     rt_field_json

Comment: No. Have to explicit decompose it into seperate fields.

Comment: Ok, so how I should build my index, if I want search only json fields? I don't need full-text search, but I can't leave **fields** in sphinx index configuration. Should I just leave full-text **fields** empty on insert, and then search on attributes? Is it right use case?